# Howto Ambient Transaction in ServiceStack.net

Tags: .net, entity-framework, transactions, servicestack

I am developing a server application using ServiceStack.net. The Database is accessed via EntityFramwork. Now I  would like to have an Ambient Transaction which is automatically commited if there were no errors/Exceptions otherwise the changes should be discarded.

Is there something out of the Box that I just haven't found yet, or do I need to roll my own?

If I have to roll my own how should I do this? First thing that comes to mind is Request and Response filters.

Answer (score 2):

I've used request and response filters to set up an ambient transaction (actually an NHibernate session in my case, but it's a similar idea). We did this by adding to the `RequestFilters` and `ResponseFilters` collection in the AppHost's `Configure` method.

We also needed to differentiate between committing a transaction on success and rolling back/clearing the transaction on any errors:

```
// normally: commit the transaction
ResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) => DbConnectionUtility.CleanupTransactionsAndConnections(req.RawUrl));

// rollback if unhandled exception in a service method
ServiceExceptionHandler = (request, exception) =>
{
    DbConnectionUtility.ClearSessions();
    // run the default code that sends a nicely serialized error response
    return DtoUtils.HandleException(this, request, exception);
};

// rollback if unhandled exception outside of service (e.g. in a filter)
var defaultExceptionHandler = ExceptionHandler;
ExceptionHandler = (httpReq, httpRes, operationName, ex) =>
{
    DbConnectionUtility.ClearSessions();
    // run the default code that sends a nicely serialized error response
    defaultExceptionHandler(httpReq, httpRes, operationName, ex);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

@esker thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Since `TransactionScope` by default rolls back if `Complete()` is not called I don't need to attach handlers for `ServiceExceptionHandler` and `ExceptionHandler`

My current solution looks like this in the AppHost file:

```
public void ConfigureFilters(Container container)
{
    RequestFilters.Add(
        (req, res, dto) =>
        req.Items.Add("transaction", new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)));

    ResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
        {
            TransactionScope transaction = null;
            var error = dto as HttpError;
            try
            {
                transaction = req.Items["transaction"] as TransactionScope;
                if (error == null)
                {
                    container.Resolve<TierDbEntitiesContainer>().SaveChanges();
                    if (transaction == null) 
                        throw new AmbientTransactionException("Transaction not found.");
                    transaction.Complete();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (transaction != null)
                    transaction.Dispose();
            }
        });
}
```